# Can you get the AWS usage report for subdirectory for buckets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can you get the AWS usage report for subdirectory for buckets? I want to know the amount of traffic of all 'GetObject' requests for all subdirectory of S3.

Comment: See [Amazon S3 Analytics – Storage Class Analysis](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/analytics-storage-class.html). You can specify reports for one or more prefixes (subdirectories).

Answer (score 1):

First, remember that there are no "subdirectories" in S3. Everything within a bucket is in a flat index and identified by an object key. However, in the AWS console, objects that contain a shared prefix are represented together in a "folder" named after the shared prefix.

With that in mind, it should be easier to understand why you cannot get an AWS usage report for a specific "subdirectory". The AWS usage report is meant to be an overview of your AWS services and is not meant to be used for more detailed analytics.

Instead there is another AWS service that allows you insight into more detailed analytics for your other AWS services: [AWS CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/). With AWS Cloudwatch you can:

- [Set up daily storage
  metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudwatch-monitoring.html)
- [Set up request (GET) metrics on a
  bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/configure-metrics.html)

And, for your specific case, you can [set up request metrics for specific prefixes (subdirectories) within a bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/configure-metrics-filter.html).

Using request metrics from AWS CloudWatch is a paid service (and another reason why you cannot get detailed request metrics in the AWS usage report).